# Excel 2013: Drop down list with date range?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013

I'm trying to create a simple drop-down list in one cell where I give a range like end of each month from 2010 till 2015 to be selectable.

How do I do that please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Build the list of values in a worksheet and use a reference to that range. To build the list of values, enter Jan-31-2014 into cell A1 (using your regional date format), then this formula in cell A2:

```
=EDATE($A$1,ROW()-1)
```

Format with the desired date format and copy down to row 72.

[image]

Comment: That's exactly what I'm trying to avoid. Using references to cells with date. I'm trying to build just a drop-down menu without any extra cells and just the desired dates in it.

Comment: May I ask why you want to avoid this? It's the easiest way to populate data validation drop-downs. Stick it in a hidden sheet and you're done. Add to the list as required. What would you want as an alternative? A named formula that produces an array of values? VBA?

Comment: You can enter the list of values directly into the list source field of the data validation dialog, of course. No cells. No mess.

Comment: This is the best way to do it. As mentioned, writing the values in manually in a comma seperated list works, but that's way to much work for me.